# Facebook share with intro and link back to site

Tags: component, extensions, plugin

I'm looking for a way to add a Facebook share button to my Joomla 3.X site that will add the  following to Facebook.

1. Article Image
2. Article Title
3. Link back to article url

This image shows the 'desired' layout (on left and highlighted in green) and the layout I currently have (on right and highlighted in red).

[image]

Any suggestions on extensions or code modifications?

Thanks!

Comment: What plugin/code are you currently using?

Comment: Unless any free/paid extension available, you have to code(in php/javascript) to arrange sharing items in desired layout before posting/sharing to facebook using most probably Fb Graph API.

Comment: I'm using AL Plugin Facebook Comments for Joomla 2.5/3.0 released by AlexLopezIT.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About Facebook wide-image layout**

Facebook chooses the layout according several internal parameters to maximize views, click-rate, etc.

There's no fixed rule.

However, there are several **recommendations** to fill:

- The aspect ratio is very specific: image widths need to be 1.91 times the height.
- For the News Feed, Facebook recommends thumbnail images of 400×209 pixels.
- Images that are smaller than these dimensions will be resized to either 154×154 or 90×90 pixels.
- On mobile, Facebook’s recommended image size is 560×292. Images smaller than this will be resized to 100×100 pixels.

**About Links back to your site**

There are several ways to submit infomation:

- Implementing Facebook "official" widgets (and associated Joomla! extensions), you are restricted to implemented features. For example **Facebook Comments**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/
- Implementing a Facebook App, and auto-posting with Facebook API your own Links or Posts. E.g. general Facebook Post definition: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post

**About Open Graph tags**

You can add Open Graph tags to your page. In this way you can better define how Facebook "reads" the page.

**About Open Graph actions**

Also, if your are submitting Posts with an App, there are new Open Graph actions to describe how the content was generated (Facebook assigns more newsfeed space to user-generated media):

- **Explicit Sharing action**, it's used to mark your posts as shared explicitly by a user  (requires Facebook approval)
- **User Generated Photo action**, to mark photos as user-generated E.g. selfies (requires Facebook approval)

**References**:

- Facebook "Official" Widgets: https://developers.facebook.com/products/sharing/
- Great article: http://www.jonloomer.com/2013/09/11/facebook-link-thumbnail-image-dimensions/
- General examples: http://www.extly.com/autotweetng-documentation-faq/577-facebook-post-layouts-how-to-choose-autotweetng-format.html
- OG Tags https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started
- OG Actions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#photos
- Facebook has an official plugin for WP, the same information about what can be done also applies to Joomla https. Plugin source code is very useful. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Anibal but in addition to his answerI would recommend a Joomla extension called [JFBConnect](http://www.sourcecoast.com/joomla-facebook/)

I use this on a few Joomla sites and it makes things a lot easier when trying to connect a Joomla site to social media channels.